# Java Mail MimeUtility encodeText UnsupportedEncodingException BASE64

Tags: java, encoding, base64, jakarta-mail

As part of my `J2EE` application's email service, I encode into `BASE64`

```
body = MimeUtility.encodeText(orig_mail_body,"UTF-8","BASE64");
```

but in some circumstances it's throwing an exception:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Unknown transfer encoding: BASE64
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encodeWord(MimeUtility.java:565)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encodeText(MimeUtility.java:373)
```

I've been trying to uncover why I get this particular message, but to no avail.
Can someone illuminate me?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the only valid values for the 'encoding' argument are "B" or "Q"; so my code should be:

```
body = MimeUtility.encodeText(orig_mail_body,"UTF-8","B");
```

Comment: Exactly.  The [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#encodeText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) are pretty clear about that, aren't they?  In general, you should never have to encode text yourself; JavaMail should take care of that for you.  The bigger question may be why you're using this method at all?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using java 8 now there is a class that can solve that.

```
byte[] bytes = orig_mail_body.getBytes();
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String encode = encoder.encodeToString(bytes);
        System.out.print(encode);
```

with spring: `org.springframework.security.crypto.codec`

```
    public static String base64Encode(String token) {
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(token.getBytes());
    return new String(encodedBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}


public static String base64Decode(String token) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(token.getBytes());
    return new String(decodedBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

with apache commons

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

```
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("Test".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));
```

Salud